# What does these symbols mean?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am learning mathematics didactically,
reading some scientific articles I find those symbols and I do not understand what they do, neither do I find informaion n googl what they mean

This is not whether it is a matrix or an exponential, which are those small letters?

$ x_{a}^{b}  $

This one I have no idea how to interpret it

$_{b}^{a}\textrm{c} $

What do the two bars do to the sides of the variable?

$\left \| b \right \|$

Comment: The answer will depend entirely on the context. These notations all could mean many different things, so you'll need to include more information to get a good answer.

Comment: Absent context, it's hard to guess what notation might mean.  For a vector $\vec v$, $||\,\vec v\,||$  often denotes the norm, as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) if that helps.  Usually authors specify what the notation they are using refers to.

Answer (score 3):

$x_a^b$ can denote $x_a$ (indexed variable) to the power $b$. In some contexts it is a tensor.

$_a^bc$ has no "standard" meaning, AFAIK.

$\|a\|$ is the (Euclidean) norm of a vector or array.